# How to customize Django ModelForm fields?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Hi I am trying to customize my ModelForm in Django. The form looks like this:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Registration
        fields = ['name', 'age', 'details'......]
```

I am trying to add different classes to different fields, along with placeholders and no labels. How do I do that? Is there a way to carry this out in the templates?

Comment: Apart from the answer, if you are using `Bootstrap` for UI then take a look at [django crispy forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add class and other parameters to a field using widget

```
   class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
      name = forms.CharField(label=' ',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textClass','placeholder':'Enter Name'}))
      details = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'special','maxlength':'100'}))
      class Meta:
         model = Registration
         fields = ['name', 'age', 'details'......]
```

For brief explanation: [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/fields/#charfield)