# Django form containing different types of fields

Tags: django

I'm wanting to add a MultipleChoiceField with a CheckboxSelectMultiple widget to a model/form containing other types of input. I am wondering how I can do this and add classes to the entire MultipleChoiceField as well as classes to each of the choices (for bootstrap). I have tried adding a class to the whole MultipleChoiceField using:

```
preferred_subjects.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

but it doesn't work. Even if it did, I also want to add classes to each of the options, but I am unsure how. I usually output forms using

```
{{ form|crispy }}
```

but since I want to add classes to each of my MultipleChoiceField options im guessing i'll need to use

```
{% for option in fieldset %}
```

and add classes as each is output. But the problem is I have other types of input in that same form which I don't want to add the class names to.

Here is my code:

```
class PersonalInformation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    dob = models.DateTimeField('Date of birth (mm/dd/yyyy)', null=True, default=now)
    subjects = model.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
```

```
class PersonalInformationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    SUBS = (
        ('MATH', 'Maths'),
        ('ENG', 'English'),
    )

    subjects = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=SUBS, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    class Meta:
        model = PersonalInformation

        fields = ['first_name', 'gender', 'subjects']
```

Summary - I want to output a form containing all different types of fields, and want to add classes to the fields and classes to the options withing the MultipleChoiceField but dont know how.

Thank you very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61426143/how-to-customize-django-modelform-fields/61426321#61426321 this can help

Comment: add a class to the subjects field and in css & select the child using class name.             Example: .subjectClass options{ color:'white'}