# How can i customize the label of model form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want to set a class or id (to make it special) to label of model form.

My forms.py :

```
from django import forms
from .models import Note

class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Note
        fields  = ['title', 'content']

        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder':'Your note...'}),
            'content': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder':'Your note...'}),
        }
```

Here i can set class fields by using widgets as you see. But when i enter the page, form labels look bad. Please check the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkeCa.jpg)

---

My modals.py :

```
class Note(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="notes")
    title   = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name="Title")
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Content")
    hour    = models.TimeField(verbose_name="Hour", auto_now_add=True)
    date    = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date", auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

And html file :

```
{% block content %}
    <div class="container notes-app">
        <h1 class="text-center text-light py-5" style="font-weight: lighter;margin-top: 100px;">Create Note :</h1>
        <form action="">
           {{ form }}
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

So basically, i want to modify label tags that `{{form}}` creates.
I searched but I could not find a solution. :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61426143/how-to-customize-django-modelform-fields/61426321#61426321 this one can help.

Comment: @GilbishKosma Hi. I can add class "fields" but i want to customize labels, not inputs.

Comment: okay i will write the answer then

Answer (score 0):

use label parameter in forms

```
from django import forms
from .models import Note

class NoteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(label='titleLabel',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder':'Your note...'}))
    content = forms.CharField(label='contentLabel',widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-input', 'placeholder':'Your note...'}))
    class Meta:
        model   = Note
        fields  = ['title', 'content']
        }
```

Comment: Hello, it doesnt fix the problem. Did you understand what i mean? I want to customize labels that comes with django's form.

 https://i.ibb.co/ctYT6KN/Ads-z.jpg

Comment: you want to customize the style of labels?